# Is there any way executing an application on windows screensaver?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I wonder that an application(windows application) can be executing on screensaver.

My customer's PC runs a screensaver automatically for security after rebooting.
And the screensaver unlocks when a user correctly logs in.

we are planning to add one more condition.
if the condition is not enough, i want to have an application runs on the screensaver that keeps lock.
The application fills with some authorization form.

Is it possible that running an application without unlocking screensaver?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In general, don't try to do security if you don't understand security. This seems like a case of misunderstood security. The screensaver doesn't "unlock" when you enter a password. It's already dismissed when you're prompted for a password. How else do you think the password dialog becomes visible?

That password dialog is the regular Windows security. it's triggered because the security settings lock the active session when the screensaver is activated.

I also have no idea what you're tyring to achieve. You're trying to "add a condition". To which list of conditions are you trying to add it? A condition is "met" or "satisfied", I've to assume a condition is not met when it is "not enough". You then want to run an application on (top?) of the screensaver. That's impossible. What does it mean to "keep unlock"? Or "fills with a form"? That's just not English.